# Display sub links under the home page url from search engine results

Tags: javascript, html, seo

I'm looking for the term or a solution for getting search engines to display sub-links under the home or landing page on a website. I've attached a screenshot of a search term and the results to better share what I would like to accomplish. Thank you so much!

[Screenshot of Links under the home page from google search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USVmC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are called Sitelinks. They are added automatically by Google and other search engines if your webpage is formatted in a way that makes it possible for search engines to scrape them.

Google provides an explanation of this formatting on the following page: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en